# Mapbox Navigation `onProgressChange()` not fired when 0.4.0-SNAPSHOT used

Tags: android, mapbox, turn-by-turn, mapbox-android

I've implemented Mapbox Navigation and lately got it working, now I want to update navigation from `0.3.1` to `0.4.0-SNAPSHOT`, unfortunately after update `onProgressChange()` not being fired even though I haven't made any changes to code.

> NOTE: `onLocationChanged` works in both cases.

**EDIT**

> NOTE: `0.3.1` still fires `onProgressChange()` although its speed is `0.0`, but not `0.4.0-SNAPSHOT`

```
public class MapActivity implements MapboxMap.OnMarkerClickListener
        ,OnMapReadyCallback, AlertLevelChangeListener, ProgressChangeListener, OffRouteListener
        ,NavigationEventListener, LocationEngineListener{


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        fabStartNavigation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // star Navigation
                startNavigation();
            }
        });
   }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        // Remove all navigation listeners being used
        mNavigation.removeNavigationEventListener(this);
        mNavigation.removeAlertLevelChangeListener(this);
        mNavigation.removeProgressChangeListener(this);
        mNavigation.removeOffRouteListener(this);

        // End the navigation session
        mNavigation.endNavigation();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }


    //navigation controller
    private void startNavigation(){
        mNavigation.addNavigationEventListener(this);
        mNavigation.addAlertLevelChangeListener(this);
        mNavigation.addOffRouteListener(this);
        mNavigation.addProgressChangeListener(this);
        mNavigation.setSnapToRoute(true);

        /*LocationEngine mLocationEngine = LostLocationEngine.getLocationEngine(this);
//        mNavigation.setLocationEngine(mLocationEngine);*/
        mLocationEngine = LostLocationEngine.getLocationEngine(this);

        mLocationEngine.setPriority(LocationEnginePriority.HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationEngine.addLocationEngineListener(this);
        mLocationEngine.activate();

        mNavigation.startNavigation(mPlannedRoute);
    }

    // navigation listeners
    @Override
    public void onAlertLevelChange(int alertLevel, RouteProgress routeProgress) {
        switch (alertLevel) {
            case HIGH_ALERT_LEVEL:
                break;
            case MEDIUM_ALERT_LEVEL:
                break;
            case LOW_ALERT_LEVEL:
                break;
            case ARRIVE_ALERT_LEVEL:
                break;
            case NONE_ALERT_LEVEL:
                break;
            case DEPART_ALERT_LEVEL:
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChange(Location location, RouteProgress routeProgress) {
    }

    @Override
    public void userOffRoute(Location location) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRunning(boolean running) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected() {
        mNavigation.setLocationEngine(mLocationEngine);
        mLocationEngine.requestLocationUpdates();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that the location updates you are receiving have no speed values? If the speed value is 0 or less, `onProgressChange` doesn't get called. If this isn't the issue, any additional information and code snippets will help to troubleshoot this.